# Mysql leave slave 1 hour behind

Tags: mysql, master-slave

Is it possible to leave the mysql slave 1 hour behind? I would like to create an script wich stops the slave when I markup some hacks such as big drop tables and stuff, to make this work I would like to stop the slave when this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `maatkit` tools, specialy at the script `mk-slave-delay` ...

BTW: When working with mysql you really want to know/use the maatkit tools. Get them, now!

Answer (score 0):

You slave does everything that your master does - so you'll just be moving the transactions back an hour - What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Get a replica, but when anything is going wrong (such as a drop database/table) stop my slave before it has run the queries.